# Need Latest Event Of Certain Type Where Several Events May Exist For That Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

First of all, I'm working in SQL Server 2000 (although prayers have been made to the Federal Stimulus Money gods for an upgrade to 2008.)

I have a listing of students and educational events. I can successfully get the most recent event, except that it may be a combination of events:

```
StudentID    Event      Date  
1            Triennial  7/1/2009  
1            Annual     7/1/2009  
2            Annual     3/3/2009  
3            Annual     6/23/2009  
3            Triennial  6/23/2009  
4            Annual     2/1/2009  
4            Triennial  2/1/2009  
5            Annual     10/1/2009
```

One event date may have two events, "Annual" and "Triennial," or it may just have one event, "Annual."  If it's a combination event, I only want to select "Triennial." If it's just an Annual event, I'll just select "Annual."

Basically, every event has "Annual," but some have "Triennial" as well, and if it's a Triennial I need to select that Event instead of the description "Annual." So for the data above, I'd want results like this:

```
StudentID    Event      Date  
1            Triennial  7/1/2009  
2            Annual     3/3/2009  
3            Triennial  6/23/2009  
4            Triennial  2/1/2009  
5            Annual     10/1/2009
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT StudentID, [Date], MAX(Event) AS [Event]
FROM   MyTable
GROUP BY StudentID, [Date]
```

Should do it.....(Triennial is "greater than" Annual)